# If $K−L=\{2,3\}$ and $K∩M=L$, then which of the following options is TRUE for the set M?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $K-L=\{2,3\}$ and $K\cap M=L$, then which of the following options is TRUE for the set $M$?
>
> 1. $\{2,3\}$
> 2. $\{1,3,5\}$
> 3. $\{1,2,3,6\}$

- A. 1 only
- B. 2 only
- C. 1 and 3
- D. 2 and 3

I think the answer is none of the options. The question is wrong.

Comment: None of them because none of them is a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Since $K\cap M = L$ we have $K-M = K-L$ so $2,3\notin M$. So none of a given answers is correct.

Comment: Can you believe this was a part of an actual official country-wide exam?

Comment: Well, they can't be proud on them self.

Comment: Nah, they are pretty proud of themselves. You can't tell them otherwise.